# Custom appearance with X forwarding over ssh

Tags: raspbian, ssh, terminal, lxde, lxsession

seeking a way to make my X forwarded session look exactly like how I have my raspbian desktop appearance on my remote host.

When I currently run `ssh -XY ***.***.*.*** lxsession` I get a default LXDE interface.

I would like the X session to be exactly as I have it setup locally on the host.

Comment: Why don't you use VNC like everyone else?

Comment: Because an X forwarded session is what I need for my purposes NOT VNC specifically. Appreciate your helpful response.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that, the X forwarded session appears to be persistent for my purposes. So any changes continue after reboot of either machine, disconnections, etc.